# Majesty Gold - How to prevent my heroes from exploring map?

Tags: majesty

Why all heros are leaving my town as soon as they are recruited? For example when I make new Rangers from Rangers Guild, they are running from town immediately for map exploration. And then they are killed by the enemy. How can I stop them in my town? I want to let them go when I place an Attack Flag.

I tried to stop them by building an Inn, but that did not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly control your heroes, but they have differing preferences for exploring.

Rangers and Rogues are notorious for running everywhere, and then either getting killed by something nasty or (worse) panicking and running home, dragging the nasty with it.

A good way to limit map exploration is *not* hire any of these guys. Instead, start with some slower heroes like Warriors or quickly upgrade and hire something like Cultists or Wizards.

They will still wander, but it'll take a lot longer as they're less likely to do it and not as quick anyway.

But in the end, heroes will wander. It's what they do in this game.

Answer (score 1):

Be strategic with where and when you place rangers. Rangers are great early-game if you need some scouting, but they're highly fragile at that point, so they aren't suitable early-on in missions involving very powerful enemies. The price you pay for exploring the map early is a lot of ranger lives. It's a trade-off you may or may not be willing to make.

Later on in a game, give your rangers lots of stuff to do in town by adding shops, carnivals, or bounties to safe locations. That will give you a better chance to keep them out of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the tag for majesty

> ...Set in a fantasy world, notable for not allowing the player to directly control the heroes they hire.

Majesty is infamous for not allowing players to have complete control over their own units.